# ListView two-way binding with observablecollection does not update automatically

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, data-binding

```
public ObservableCollection<App> Apps { get; set; }

public MainWindow()
{
    Apps = LoadApps();
    listview.ItemsSource = Apps;
}

public void AnotherMethod()
{
    Apps = LoadApps();
}
```

It works when assigned to ItemsSource but I need the ListView to be updated every time the Apps content is changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by "Apps content"? If you replace the whole reference with a new collection you need to [implement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229614.aspx) [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) in `MainWindow`. If the items change internally and you want updates in the `ListView` you need to implement said interface in `App`.

*(Note about the first possibility: Often you would not allow the replacement of the reference by creating a `private readonly` field, obviously the public property exposing it would only have a getter.)*

Comment: I implemented INotifyPropertyChanged in App, it works as expected, meaning, if I change any App.property it reflects in the ListViewItem and vice-versa. However if I reassign Apps with a different set of observablecollection I still see the same old result in the ListView.

Comment: I'm okay reassigning ItemsSource, it works. I am just wondering why it wouldn't work without the second line

1.    Apps = LoadApps();
2.    listview.ItemsSource = Apps;

Comment: @gangt: How would the ListView know that the Apps reference changed? You did not implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in `MainWindow` so the Apps-property does not create any notifications. ObservableCollections only notify on internal changes to the collection, they do not know anything about references to themselves. As i said, either implement the interface or make the collection readonly (and `Clear` it then `Add` the new items if you need to change it).

Comment: I guess that's right, somehow I assumed it wrong. I tried implementing  INotifyPropertyChanged on MainWindow but it was throwing error [mainwindow does not implement interface member]. Anyway, I guess I understand where I'm going/thinking wrong.

Comment: Like, maybe the error message is a place to start? "Does not implement interface member".  Do you implement INotifyPropertyChanged?

Answer (score 1):

ObservableCollection only update ListView items when items on collection was updated.
you can do something like

```
public void AnotherMethod()
{
    var apps = LoadApps();
    Apps.Clear();
    Apps.AddRange(apps);
}
```

or define Apps as a Dependency Property and bind it to list view ItemSource:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty AppsProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Apps", typeof (ObservableCollection<App>), typeof (YourClass), new PropertyMetadata(default(ObservableCollection<App>)));

public ObservableCollection<App> Apps
{
    get { return (ObservableCollection<App>) GetValue(AppsProperty); }
    set { SetValue(AppsProperty, value); }
}

public MainWindow()
{
    Apps = LoadApps();
    listview.SetBinding(ListView.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding("Apps"){Source = this})
}
```